# Accessing Google Photos using only a sharing link

Tags: google-photos-api

I am trying to access a Google Photos album that has been shared via a sharing link.  A UX user can access such an album without authenticating, simply by following the sharing link.

However, all APIs in Google Photos API that I can find require the user's OAuth token, and I do not wish to require the users to log in (as they are not required to do so in a browser).

I tried scraping the HTML output returned by Google Photos in response to the link, but it is quite difficult (not to mention fragile).

Any suggestions?